# Rails Scope issue with ActiveRecord::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I'm kind of new to rails and I just discovered serializers.

I proceed with the implementation for one of my model. I generated a serializer with

```
rails g serializer MyModel
```

Then in my controller, in my function that renders my data I do this :

```
render json: MyModel.where(...), each_serializer: MyModelSerializer, root: false
# note : that's the only line in my function
```

And finally my serializer :

```
class MyModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, ... # all attributes in my model, I double-checked
end
```

The error i now get from the rails server is the following :

```
uninitialized constant MyModelController::MyModelSerializer
```

Am I missing something ? :(

Thanks for your help :)

By the way, I'll add that the function that is supposed to render json with the serializer is called with an ajax request from the view. Don't know if it changes things though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this bit in your controller code:

```
each_serializer: ::MyModelSerializer
```

Two colon basically forces Ruby interpreter to look for `MyModelSerializer` class in the "root" and not within `MyModelController`. From your error message, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Still the almost same error. But this time it ommits the controller scope : "uninitialized constant MyModelSerializer"

Comment: It means that it can't access it. Where is your `MyModelSerializer` file located?

Comment: I think that my files paths are classic. My models are in /app/models/. , the controllers in /app/controllers/. and now my only serializer is in /app/serializers/.

I did not created the folders (I think, don't really remember) they were created with the generates methods that rails offers.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `rails-api` gem? Which version of Rails are you on?

Comment: I just redo all of my database and now it works like a charm... I now feel silly :/ Sorry for the (unnecessary) disturbance.
Thank you so much for your help and the attention you had to my problem :)
Take care ! :)